# jack audio and multiple audio devices with alsa_out

Tags: audio, alsa, jack

Does anybody knows why I can't use two instances of alsa_out with jack? I have 3 soundcards and I want to use them at the same time. I have one inside my computer and two usb devices. This is my setup:

```
 0 [PCH            ]: HDA-Intel - HDA Intel PCH
                      HDA Intel PCH at 0xf1c00000 irq 47
 1 [Pro            ]: USB-Audio - SB X-Fi Surround 5.1 Pro
                      Creative Technology Ltd SB X-Fi Surround 5.1 Pro at usb-0000:04:00.0-1, full sp
 2 [Pro_1          ]: USB-Audio - SB X-Fi Surround 5.1 Pro
                      Creative Technology Ltd SB X-Fi Surround 5.1 Pro at usb-0000:04:00.0-2, full sp
```

So if i start the jack server on hw:0 device i can start only one usb card with hw:1 or hw:2 (usually i use hw:Pro and hw:Pro_1) with this command:

```
alsa_out -j "Alsa Dedicated Input 0" -d hw:Pro -c 6 -q 2 -r 48000
```

the second istance of alsa out:

```
alsa_out -j "Alsa Dedicated Input 0" -d hw:Pro_1 -c 6 -q 2 -r 48000
```

Says: The device is busy or it can not access it ant i can start the instance only with dmix: Pro_1, but i can use only 2 channels and I want to use all 6 of them.

I tried with ~/.asoundrc to merge all the soundcards but nothing happens. I don't know how to make it works. I use both ubuntu 11.10 and ubuntu studio 11.10 and i tried to make it works on both OS.

can anyone help me with that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just in case somebody else is looking for the answer.
aplay -L (note cap L) will give you several entries with different prefixes such as hw dmix dsnoop ...
hw in particular is direct to the hardware and does not allow sharing that's why your second call fails try dmix for example.